# MySQL query to get same column data in two rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I am new to MySQL. I have a database and I am facing issue to getting the data in the format below.

Table is as below

```
+----+------+-------+-+
| ID | ign  | time  | |
+----+------+-------+-+
|  1 | NULL | 12:30 | |
|  2 |    1 | 12:31 | |
|  3 | NULL | 12:32 | |
|  4 | NULL | 12:33 | |
|  5 | NULL | 12:34 | |
|  6 |    0 | 12:35 | |
|  7 | NULL | 12:36 | |
|  8 | NULL | 12:37 | |
|  9 |    1 | 12:38 | |
| 10 | NULL | 12:39 | |
| 11 | NULL | 12:40 | |
| 12 | NULL | 12:41 | |
| 13 |    0 | 12:42 | |
| 14 | NULL | 12:43 | |
| 15 | NULL | 12:44 | |
+----+------+-------+-+
```

My Resultant table should be in the below format.

```
Start | Start Time | Stop |Stop Time
1     | 12:31      | 0    | 12:35
1     | 12:38      | 0    | 12:42
```

The result is obtained by alternate 1s and 0s put together. The first ign with value 1 is the start and the 2nd ign with value 0 is the stop. The time value of the respective 1 and 0 is the start and stop time.I am completely new to MySQL and have no idea how this can be achieved.

Comment: Why are the id's all over the place and duplicated?

Comment: And you appear to have no PRIMARY KEY, which is likely to cause severe problems a little way down the road

Comment: The IDs being duplicated was a typo mistake. The result is obtained by alternate 1s and 0s put together. The first ign  with value 1 is the start and the 2nd ign with value 0 is the stop. The time value of the respective 1 and 0 is the start and stop time.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.ign `Start`, t.time `Start Time`, 0 `Stop`,
  (select min(time) from tablename where ign = 0 and time > t.time) `Stop Time`
from tablename t 
where t.ign = 1
```

For every row where `ign = 1` the subquery returns the minimum later time where `ign = 0`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/feVPfC7gFtvbo978L23ehf/1).
Results:

```
| Start | Start Time | Stop | Stop Time |
| ----- | ---------- | ---- | --------- |
| 1     | 12:31      | 0    | 12:35     |
| 1     | 12:38      | 0    | 12:42     |
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a kind of gaps-and-islands problem. You could do a window sum to define the groups: ignoring `ign`s which are `null`s, a new group starts every time a `1` is met.

For your dataset, the following query would produce the expected results:

```
select 1 start, min(time) startTime, 0 stop, max(time) stopTime
from (
    select t.*, sum(ign) over(order by time) grp
    from mytable t
    where ign is not null
) t
group by grp
```

Note that window functions were added in MySQL 8.0.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fea8eb830f72253b3d56ab0854313923)**:

```
start | startTime | stop | stopTime
----: | :-------- | ---: | :-------
    1 | 12:31     |    0 | 12:35   
    1 | 12:38     |    0 | 12:42
```